# How to convert a plain JS object to an Immutable collection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I have parts of a state managed with the help of Immutable collections.
For example,

```
const FolderModel = Record({
    id: null,
    name: '',
    items: List()
})

const DocsModel = Record({
    folder1: new FolderModel({
        id: 1,
        name: 'Избранное'
    }),
    folder2: new FolderModel({
        id: 2,
        name: 'Отложенное'
    }),
    folder3: new FolderModel({
        id: 3,
        name: 'Топ тендеры'
    })
})

const initialState = new DocsModel()
```

I also save my state in a `localStorage`, so the problem is when retrieve the state from `localStorage` I don't know how to convert JS object back to a nested collection (e.g Record containing a field that is a List).
I already tried using `Immutable.fromJS()` method but apparently it doesn't work for `Record`s. Did anybody face the same problem? Please help resolving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success using the [transit-immutable-js](https://github.com/glenjamin/transit-immutable-js) lib.

From the [docs](https://github.com/glenjamin/transit-immutable-js#api):

*"Transit is a serialisation format which builds on top of JSON to provide a richer set of types. It is extensible, which makes it a good choice for easily providing serialisation and deserialisation capabilities for Immutable's types."*

Example usage with Records:

```
var FooRecord = Immutable.Record({ a: 1, b: 2, }, 'Foo'),
    foo = new FooRecord(),
    serialize = transit.withRecords([FooRecord]),
    json = serialize.toJSON(foo);

console.log(json); //=> json string of your data
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to serialize your collection with `JSON.stringify()` before setting it to localStorage. After getting it back from localStorage you can deserialize it with `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Sorry for misguiding you, but I already did that. The problem is when I get the state back from localStorage it is returned as a plain JS object. Thus, I have problems further retrieving data from store as I designed my `mapStateToProps` method to deal with Immutable Collections (e.g `filter: state.filter.get('filter'))`